# Safely zeroing buffers after working with crypto/*

Tags: security, go, cryptography

Is there a way to zero buffers containing e. g. private keys after
using them and make sure that compilers don't delete the zeroing code as
unused?  Something tells me that a simple:

```golang
copy(privateKey, make([]byte, keySize))
```

Is not guaranteed to stay there.

Comment: Why on earth would a compiler remove code that is not a no-op? This specific example would break _so_ many things.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks  Not sure what you mean.  C compilers do that all the time, and it's a known issue.  See [this article](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-04-how-to-zero-a-buffer.html) for example.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting! Not something I've run into before. I'm curious - rather than trying to reason about what hypothetical compilers may or may not do, and trick them into thinking the zeroed buffer is used, why not actually use it? Say, pass it to a function that adds its byte values to a global counter, then panics if the counter value is nonzero. Of course this adds a bit of computation but for most purposes it seems like it should be relatively trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to prevent sensitive data remaining in memory. But have you considered the data might have been replicated, or swapped to disk?

For these reasons I use the https://github.com/awnumar/memguard package.
It provides features to destroy the data when no longer required, while keeping it safe in the mean time.

You can read about its background here; https://spacetime.dev/memory-security-go

Comment: Before using memguard, I would recommend reading this critique of its approach:  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14174500.  The basic problem is that Go's GC can make copies of your buffers under the hood, ones that memguard cannot see and therefore cannot clear.

Comment: @fsctl Very good post, but that was concerning version v0.1.0. Most has already been fixed in v0.2.0 in 2017; https://github.com/awnumar/memguard/pull/5   
And more improvements since.

Answer (score 3):

How about checking (some of) the content of the buffer after zeroing it and passing it to another function? For example:

```
copy(privateKey, make([]byte, keySize))

if privateKey[0] != 0 {
    // If you pass the buffer to another function,
    // this check and above copy() can't be optimized away:
    fmt.Println("Zeroing failed", privateKey[0])
}
```

To be absolutely safe, you could XOR the passed buffer content with random bytes, but if / since the zeroing is not optimized away, the `if` body is never reached.

You might think a very intelligent compiler might deduce the above `copy()` zeros `privateKey[0]` and thus determine the condition is always false and still optimize it away (although this is very unlikely). The solution to this is not to use `make([]byte, keySize)` but e.g. a slice coming from a global variable or a function argument (whose value can only be determined at runtime) so the compiler can't be smart enough to deduce the condition is going to be always false at compile time.

Comment: I thought about that myself, but a _Sufficiently Smart Compiler_ could infer that as well.  I was looking something “guaranteed by spec”, but if there isn't such function, I could accept that as well.

Comment: @Ainar-G If you have a package level variable `var ZeroBuf []byte`, a compiler can't be smart enough to optimize away copying it because any other package could change its value at runtime, at any time.

Comment: GC might copy the key, leaving the original behind to be freed. It's true that *current* Go does not use a copying GC (so as long as you don't go over a slice's current cap, the underlying array won't move) but I'd be really cautious here.